# How to access createjs instance from zim npm

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, adobe-animate

My project is developed using createjs in react framework. I have added zimjs npm in my project.
on console.log(zim) I found zim object contains window.createjs, I can't figure out how to access createjs library. I don't anything for this in zim docs. I tired `zim.createjs, window.createjs` nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

ZIM expects createjs to be in the global scope.  So if you have window.createjs then try adding const createjs = window.createjs; before creating the ZIM Frame.  (I am not sure what you mean by there is a window.createjs inside the zim object.  That would be a little odd).